# ¿Cómo puedo mantener un valor obtenido de un switch introducido a un elemento <p>?

Tags: javascript, html

En éste ejercicio quiero obtener los dos primeros valores numéricos introducidos en un ***input***, compararlo en un ***switch*** e introducirlos en un elemento html ***p***.

Éste es el código js:

```js
function province() {
  var zipcode = document.getElementById("zipcode");
  var zip = zipcode.value;
  switch (zip.substring(0, 2)) {
    case "01":
      text = "Álava";
      break;
    case "02":
      text = "Albacete";
      break;
    case "03":
      text = "Alicante";
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("zipcode2").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="number" id="zipcode"><button id="localize" onclick="province()">Localize</button><br/>
  </form>
  <p id="zipcode2"></p>
  <script src="3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Cuando ejecuto el código el resultado aparece de forma momentánea y desaparece.
Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un problema que tienes es que `text` no está definido.

Antes del `switch` se inicializa. Yo le puse un texto en caso de que no entre en ningun `case` del `switch`.

Otro problema es que envia la información del `form` (en jsfiddle se quejaba de que no ponía `method="POST"`) porque el tag `<button>` hace submit del formulario.

Asi que cambié el `<button>` por un `<input type="button">` y ya funciona.

```js
function province() {
  var zipcode = document.getElementById("zipcode");
  var zip = zipcode.value;
  var text = "not found";
  switch (zip.substring(0, 2)) {
    case "01":
      text = "Álava";
      break;
    case "02":
      text = "Albacete";
      break;
    case "03":
      text = "Alicante";
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("zipcode2").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="number" id="zipcode"><input type="button" id="localize" onclick="province()" value="Localize"><br/>
  </form>
  <p id="zipcode2"></p>
  <script src="3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Otra solución habría sido pasar el evento a `province( event )` y luego en el método usar `event.preventDefault()` para evitar que haga el `submit` del formulario.

```js
function province(e) {
  var zipcode = document.getElementById("zipcode");
  var zip = zipcode.value;
  var text = "not found";
  switch (zip.substring(0, 2)) {
    case "01":
      text = "Álava";
      break;
    case "02":
      text = "Albacete";
      break;
    case "03":
      text = "Alicante";
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("zipcode2").innerHTML = text;
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="number" id="zipcode"><button id="localize" onclick="province(event)">Localize</button><br/>
  </form>
  <p id="zipcode2"></p>
  <script src="3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

O poner el evento `onsubmit="return false;"` en el `<form>`.

```js
function province() {
  var zipcode = document.getElementById("zipcode");
  var zip = zipcode.value;
  var text = "not found";
  switch (zip.substring(0, 2)) {
    case "01":
      text = "Álava";
      break;
    case "02":
      text = "Albacete";
      break;
    case "03":
      text = "Alicante";
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById("zipcode2").innerHTML = text;

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="number" id="zipcode"><button id="localize" onclick="province()">Localize</button><br/>
  </form>
  <p id="zipcode2"></p>
  <script src="3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

(Gracias @OscarGarcia por [tu comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137363/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-mantener-un-valor-obtenido-de-un-switch-introducido-a-un-elemento-p/137366#comment256567_137366))

Comment: Creo que estaría bien comentarle lo del `onsubmit="return false;"` o el `preventDefault` de los eventos, etc para que entienda que tras el evento `onclick` se producirá el envío del formulario.

Comment: Te me adelantaste :) Estaba escribiendo un fragmento con el uso de `preventDefault()`, ya que el problema principal era que el formulario se estaba enviando y refrescando la página. Convendría que ponga esto en el  botón: **`onclick="province(event);"`** y en la función de JS: `function province(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); //...resto de tu respuesta`